# Not allowed all number in an input or all number with space

Tags: regex

Not allowed all number in an input or all number with space

ex:

INVALID INPUTS

```
"12132" - not valid
" 123332" - not valid(all numbers with space)
"123 332" - not valid(all numbers with space)
"123332 " - not valid(all numbers with space)
```

VALID INPUT

```
" 1212$ aa" - valid(includes special character)

"aa$1212baaa" -valid
"valid"
"valid223"
"valid @ 123"
```

Im using this regex   `"(?!^\d+$)^.+$"` but I couldn't get rid of the all number with space

Comment: How about `""`? `" "`?

Comment: small modification to your regex try (?!^[\d\s]+$)^.+$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to match the invalid strings, this should be relatively simple:

```
^[\d ]+$
```

Comment: The empty string would be best checked outside the regex as well. Language dependent. `if (input && !(input ~= /^[\d ]+$/))` for example

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if there is a non-digit non-space character in your string:

```
[^0-9\s]
```

If there is, you're done !

Answer (score 0):

to match valid strings use this pattern `^(?=.*[^0-9\s])(.*)$` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mO5tJ4)